# Multiple drives, multiple OSes with no access between

Tags: hard-drive, bios, multi-boot, desktop-computer, hardware-rec

I want to get a few more hard drives for my PC to install different operating systems on them, but I dont want any of the operating systems to have access to the other drives.

For example: OS A, only has access to its own drive, same with OS B and C.

I'm really not sure how i'd word this question to google, else I'd probably have found my answer by now.

edit: I'd really rather the drives be physically inaccessible (disconnected/unpowered) so as to prevent any malicious actor gaining access to any other drive.

Comment: An OS can be configured not to use a particular device/partition/filesystem. Is this enough? Or do you want some devices to be inaccessible even if the OS is compromised and the attacker actively tries to access as much as possible? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] the question and clarify.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd really rather the drives be physically inaccessible (disconnected/unpowered) so as to prevent any malicious actor gaining access to any other drive.

To my knowledge commercial physical drive toggles don't exist. Making one would be possible, but not quite safe - you'd be able to accidentally power a drive on while the computer is running (breaking the isolation) or power it off (preventing OS's access mid-operation).

Motherboard firmware (UEFI) doesn't support per-OS configuration switching.

I'd suggest using virtual machines to achieve this goal. VMs are self-contained and can't access each other's disks. The hypervisor will enforce security and prevent unsafe hardware changes to a running VM. The overhead of virtualization is minimal on modern hardware. For your use case a type 1 hypervisor would be appropriate, like for example VMware ESXi. You could also consider Unraid, although its primary use case is different.

Comment: VMs are not totally out of the question but i'd really rather something physical. can I ask if you've ever seen or heard of something like this? : https://www.amazon.com/Iceyon-Control-Selector-Interfaces-Computer/dp/B081N6WWRV/

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this by getting a (hot) swappable drive tray and just putting in the appropriate disk - nominally something like [https://www.amazon.com/Kingwin-Universal-Tray-Less-Backplane-Enclosure/dp/B00M3WNWB2/ref=mp_s_a_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=hard+drive+caddy+sata+removable&qid=1609143349&sr=8-6#immersive-view_1609143508550](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00M3WNWB2)

You might have an interesting problem (but not an unsolvable one) if you boot using UEFI, but if you use legacy boot this should not be an issue.

Comment: I found this in a list from https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hard+drive+caddy+sata+removable&page=3&qid=1609143789&ref=is_pn_2 - it has a lot of options which could work (and a lot that won't)

Comment: I'd be a bit worried about drive connector's durability. UEFI may or may not be a problem; for example Dells seem to remember entries for removed drives.

Comment: @gronostaj good call - https://www.google.com/url?q=https://docs.rs-online.com/8a01/0900766b816ae4a4.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjzx4PuqPHtAhV5zDgGHUD1AogQFjAAegQIDhAB&usg=AOvVaw3XMykwqlHGwVtOP26bJm3v talks about a duty cycle rating of 500 connections.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, I also like the look of what I just found on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/Iceyon-Control-Selector-Interfaces-Computer/dp/B081N6WWRV/
 by the looks of it, you can choose which drive will get power, then power on the machine. only thing i'd worry about is the switch failing and cutting power mid use.